# How can I track logged time into my linux machine?

Tags: linux

Scenario is like this:
OS : centos

I logged in to my machine and then lock using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. For unlock I need to enter my password which unlock my machine. So I need to track time at which my PC unlocks with out root permission.

Thanks!

Comment: define `who` please, if it is just a user session unlock for sure the user is always the same one. How could be possible to detect who is the person that unlocked the session? try to type `last` command and check if this is something that can help you

Comment: @lese who and last comment provide information based on whether new terminal is opened or not. But what If I work on already opened terminal after unlock ?

Comment: mmm, I guess you could make a script to shot a picture with your webcam everytime your session is unlocked. Just joking, please, define `who` : )

Comment: If I am unlocking with a username `xyz` here I am assuming that `xyz` has unlocked this machine , I just want to know time at which user unlocks the machine.

Comment: @lese Changed title of question.

Comment: I found answer at http://superuser.com/a/668628

Answer (score 0):

When you lock with Ctrl+Alt+L, most likely you simply enable a screen saver application which also asks for a password.
I think there is no automatic way, unless you tweak the screen saver application to track it.

For example you can create a wrapper script which will log the time and start the screen saver, and log time when it is finished, though it is not trivial.